# Policy Gradient Methods

Tags: reinforcement-learning

would be really thankful if someone could clear this up.

In reinforcement learning, When we use basis like the fourier or say polynomial basis, and say we have 4 actions, theta will then be a N x4 dimensional vector, where we dedicated each column to each action right..so q(s,a) would be theta[:,a]*feature(s)
how would we do this if we try a policy gradient approach?

So we use softmax, we still can use features independent of the actions, how do we satisy the compatability conditions in an actor critic settings? Say actor is softmax, does critic =w.T * phi(s) work ok?